# linear operator on a finite dimensional vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $T$ be a linear operator on a finite-dimensional vector space. Prove the following result:

a)$N(T^* T)=N(T)$. Deduce that $\operatorname{rank}(T^*T)=\operatorname{rank}(T)$

b)$\operatorname{rank}(T)=\operatorname{rank}(T^*)$. Deduce from (a) that $\operatorname{rank}(TT^*)=\operatorname{rank}(T)$

I have proved the part(a) but in part(b) I am stuck. I have started proving $\operatorname{rank}(T)=\operatorname{rank}(T^*)$ by using the definition that $T^*= \overline{T^t} $ and we know that $\operatorname{rank}(T)=\operatorname{rank}(T^t)$ but I can't seem to prove $\operatorname{rank}(T)=\operatorname{rank}(\overline{T})$

Answer (score 1):

One way is to show that nullity $\overline{T} =$ nullity $T$, then use the rank-nullity theorem. We have that $$Tx = 0 \iff \overline T \overline x = \overline 0 = 0$$
and so if $x \in \text{null } T,$ then $\overline x \in \text{null } \overline T.$ Therefore, if $\left\{v_1, \ldots, v_k \right\}$ form a basis for null $T$, then $\left\{\overline{v}_1, \ldots, \overline{v}_k \right\}$ form a basis for null $\overline T$. So we see that $\text{nullity } T = \text{nullity } \overline{T}.$ Now, use the rank-nullity theorem, and you're done.